# Autoconf 2.68 "make" errors

Tags: autoconf

I am new to Linux so I am having trouble figuring out how to solve these errors. It is configuring correctly but I am having no luck with the make command. I have already installed GNU m4 needed for this as well.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/autoconf
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure: autobuild project... GNU Autoconf
configure: autobuild revision... 2.68
configure: autobuild hostname... nickallen-TZ68A
configure: autobuild timestamp... 20150611T193409Z
checking whether /bin/sh -n is known to work... no
checking for characters that cannot appear in file names... none
checking whether directories can have trailing spaces... yes
checking for expr... /usr/bin/expr
checking for GNU M4 that supports accurate traces... /usr/bin/m4
checking whether /usr/bin/m4 accepts --gnu... yes
checking how m4 supports trace files... --debugfile
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking whether /usr/bin/perl Fcntl::flock is implemented... yes
checking for emacs... no
checking for xemacs... no
checking for emacs... no
checking where .elc files should go... ${datadir}/emacs/site-lisp
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking whether make is case sensitive... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/atlocal
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/emacs/Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/Autom4te/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/autoscan/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/m4sugar/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/autoconf/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/autotest/Makefile
config.status: creating bin/Makefile
config.status: executing tests/atconfig commands
nickallen@nickallen-TZ68A:~/autoconf-2.68$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68'
Making all in bin
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/bin'
rm -f autom4te autom4te.tmp
srcdir=''; \
  test -f ./autom4te.in || srcdir=./; \
  sed -e 's|@SHELL[@]|/bin/bash|g' -e 's|@PERL[@]|/usr/bin/perl|g' -e 's|@PERL_FLOCK[@]|yes|g' -e 's|@bindir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/bin|g' -e 's|@pkgdatadir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/share/autoconf|g' -e 's|@prefix[@]|/usr/local/autoconf|g' -e 's|@autoconf-name[@]|'`echo autoconf | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autoheader-name[@]|'`echo autoheader | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autom4te-name[@]|'`echo autom4te | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@M4[@]|/usr/bin/m4|g' -e 's|@M4_DEBUGFILE[@]|--debugfile|g' -e 's|@M4_GNU[@]|--gnu|g' -e 's|@AWK[@]|mawk|g' -e 's|@RELEASE_YEAR[@]|'`sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/;q' ../ChangeLog`'|g' -e 's|@VERSION[@]|2.68|g' -e 's|@PACKAGE_NAME[@]|GNU Autoconf|g' -e 's|@configure_input[@]|Generated from autom4te.in; do not edit by hand.|g' ${srcdir}autom4te.in >autom4te.tmp
chmod +x autom4te.tmp
chmod a-w autom4te.tmp
mv autom4te.tmp autom4te
autom4te_perllibdir='..'/lib AUTOM4TE_CFG='../lib/autom4te.cfg'         ../bin/autom4te -B '..'/lib -B '..'/lib         --language M4sh --cache '' --melt ./autoconf.as -o autoconf.in
rm -f autoconf autoconf.tmp
srcdir=''; \
  test -f ./autoconf.in || srcdir=./; \
  sed -e 's|@SHELL[@]|/bin/bash|g' -e 's|@PERL[@]|/usr/bin/perl|g' -e 's|@PERL_FLOCK[@]|yes|g' -e 's|@bindir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/bin|g' -e 's|@pkgdatadir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/share/autoconf|g' -e 's|@prefix[@]|/usr/local/autoconf|g' -e 's|@autoconf-name[@]|'`echo autoconf | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autoheader-name[@]|'`echo autoheader | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autom4te-name[@]|'`echo autom4te | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@M4[@]|/usr/bin/m4|g' -e 's|@M4_DEBUGFILE[@]|--debugfile|g' -e 's|@M4_GNU[@]|--gnu|g' -e 's|@AWK[@]|mawk|g' -e 's|@RELEASE_YEAR[@]|'`sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/;q' ../ChangeLog`'|g' -e 's|@VERSION[@]|2.68|g' -e 's|@PACKAGE_NAME[@]|GNU Autoconf|g' -e 's|@configure_input[@]|Generated from autoconf.in; do not edit by hand.|g' ${srcdir}autoconf.in >autoconf.tmp
chmod +x autoconf.tmp
chmod a-w autoconf.tmp
mv autoconf.tmp autoconf
rm -f autoheader autoheader.tmp
srcdir=''; \
  test -f ./autoheader.in || srcdir=./; \
  sed -e 's|@SHELL[@]|/bin/bash|g' -e 's|@PERL[@]|/usr/bin/perl|g' -e 's|@PERL_FLOCK[@]|yes|g' -e 's|@bindir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/bin|g' -e 's|@pkgdatadir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/share/autoconf|g' -e 's|@prefix[@]|/usr/local/autoconf|g' -e 's|@autoconf-name[@]|'`echo autoconf | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autoheader-name[@]|'`echo autoheader | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autom4te-name[@]|'`echo autom4te | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@M4[@]|/usr/bin/m4|g' -e 's|@M4_DEBUGFILE[@]|--debugfile|g' -e 's|@M4_GNU[@]|--gnu|g' -e 's|@AWK[@]|mawk|g' -e 's|@RELEASE_YEAR[@]|'`sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/;q' ../ChangeLog`'|g' -e 's|@VERSION[@]|2.68|g' -e 's|@PACKAGE_NAME[@]|GNU Autoconf|g' -e 's|@configure_input[@]|Generated from autoheader.in; do not edit by hand.|g' ${srcdir}autoheader.in >autoheader.tmp
chmod +x autoheader.tmp
chmod a-w autoheader.tmp
mv autoheader.tmp autoheader
rm -f autoreconf autoreconf.tmp
srcdir=''; \
  test -f ./autoreconf.in || srcdir=./; \
  sed -e 's|@SHELL[@]|/bin/bash|g' -e 's|@PERL[@]|/usr/bin/perl|g' -e 's|@PERL_FLOCK[@]|yes|g' -e 's|@bindir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/bin|g' -e 's|@pkgdatadir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/share/autoconf|g' -e 's|@prefix[@]|/usr/local/autoconf|g' -e 's|@autoconf-name[@]|'`echo autoconf | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autoheader-name[@]|'`echo autoheader | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autom4te-name[@]|'`echo autom4te | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@M4[@]|/usr/bin/m4|g' -e 's|@M4_DEBUGFILE[@]|--debugfile|g' -e 's|@M4_GNU[@]|--gnu|g' -e 's|@AWK[@]|mawk|g' -e 's|@RELEASE_YEAR[@]|'`sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/;q' ../ChangeLog`'|g' -e 's|@VERSION[@]|2.68|g' -e 's|@PACKAGE_NAME[@]|GNU Autoconf|g' -e 's|@configure_input[@]|Generated from autoreconf.in; do not edit by hand.|g' ${srcdir}autoreconf.in >autoreconf.tmp
chmod +x autoreconf.tmp
chmod a-w autoreconf.tmp
mv autoreconf.tmp autoreconf
rm -f ifnames ifnames.tmp
srcdir=''; \
  test -f ./ifnames.in || srcdir=./; \
  sed -e 's|@SHELL[@]|/bin/bash|g' -e 's|@PERL[@]|/usr/bin/perl|g' -e 's|@PERL_FLOCK[@]|yes|g' -e 's|@bindir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/bin|g' -e 's|@pkgdatadir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/share/autoconf|g' -e 's|@prefix[@]|/usr/local/autoconf|g' -e 's|@autoconf-name[@]|'`echo autoconf | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autoheader-name[@]|'`echo autoheader | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autom4te-name[@]|'`echo autom4te | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@M4[@]|/usr/bin/m4|g' -e 's|@M4_DEBUGFILE[@]|--debugfile|g' -e 's|@M4_GNU[@]|--gnu|g' -e 's|@AWK[@]|mawk|g' -e 's|@RELEASE_YEAR[@]|'`sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/;q' ../ChangeLog`'|g' -e 's|@VERSION[@]|2.68|g' -e 's|@PACKAGE_NAME[@]|GNU Autoconf|g' -e 's|@configure_input[@]|Generated from ifnames.in; do not edit by hand.|g' ${srcdir}ifnames.in >ifnames.tmp
chmod +x ifnames.tmp
chmod a-w ifnames.tmp
mv ifnames.tmp ifnames
rm -f autoscan autoscan.tmp
srcdir=''; \
  test -f ./autoscan.in || srcdir=./; \
  sed -e 's|@SHELL[@]|/bin/bash|g' -e 's|@PERL[@]|/usr/bin/perl|g' -e 's|@PERL_FLOCK[@]|yes|g' -e 's|@bindir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/bin|g' -e 's|@pkgdatadir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/share/autoconf|g' -e 's|@prefix[@]|/usr/local/autoconf|g' -e 's|@autoconf-name[@]|'`echo autoconf | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autoheader-name[@]|'`echo autoheader | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autom4te-name[@]|'`echo autom4te | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@M4[@]|/usr/bin/m4|g' -e 's|@M4_DEBUGFILE[@]|--debugfile|g' -e 's|@M4_GNU[@]|--gnu|g' -e 's|@AWK[@]|mawk|g' -e 's|@RELEASE_YEAR[@]|'`sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/;q' ../ChangeLog`'|g' -e 's|@VERSION[@]|2.68|g' -e 's|@PACKAGE_NAME[@]|GNU Autoconf|g' -e 's|@configure_input[@]|Generated from autoscan.in; do not edit by hand.|g' ${srcdir}autoscan.in >autoscan.tmp
chmod +x autoscan.tmp
chmod a-w autoscan.tmp
mv autoscan.tmp autoscan
rm -f autoupdate autoupdate.tmp
srcdir=''; \
  test -f ./autoupdate.in || srcdir=./; \
  sed -e 's|@SHELL[@]|/bin/bash|g' -e 's|@PERL[@]|/usr/bin/perl|g' -e 's|@PERL_FLOCK[@]|yes|g' -e 's|@bindir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/bin|g' -e 's|@pkgdatadir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/share/autoconf|g' -e 's|@prefix[@]|/usr/local/autoconf|g' -e 's|@autoconf-name[@]|'`echo autoconf | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autoheader-name[@]|'`echo autoheader | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autom4te-name[@]|'`echo autom4te | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@M4[@]|/usr/bin/m4|g' -e 's|@M4_DEBUGFILE[@]|--debugfile|g' -e 's|@M4_GNU[@]|--gnu|g' -e 's|@AWK[@]|mawk|g' -e 's|@RELEASE_YEAR[@]|'`sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/;q' ../ChangeLog`'|g' -e 's|@VERSION[@]|2.68|g' -e 's|@PACKAGE_NAME[@]|GNU Autoconf|g' -e 's|@configure_input[@]|Generated from autoupdate.in; do not edit by hand.|g' ${srcdir}autoupdate.in >autoupdate.tmp
chmod +x autoupdate.tmp
chmod a-w autoupdate.tmp
mv autoupdate.tmp autoupdate
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/bin'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68'
Making all in lib
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib'
Making all in Autom4te
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib/Autom4te'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib/Autom4te'
Making all in m4sugar
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib/m4sugar'
:;{ \
  echo '# This file is part of -*- Autoconf -*-.' && \
  echo '# Version of Autoconf.' && \
  echo '# Copyright (C) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2006, 2007, 2009' && \
  echo '# Free Software Foundation, Inc.' && \
  echo  &&\
  echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_NAME],      [GNU Autoconf])' && \
  echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_TARNAME],   [autoconf])' && \
  echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_VERSION],   [2.68])' && \
  echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_STRING],    [GNU Autoconf 2.68])' && \
  echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_BUGREPORT], [bug-autoconf@gnu.org])' && \
  echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_URL],       [http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/])' && \
  echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_YEAR],      ['`sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/;q' ../../ChangeLog`'])'; \
} > version.m4-t
mv version.m4-t version.m4
autom4te_perllibdir='../..'/lib AUTOM4TE_CFG='../../lib/autom4te.cfg'         ../../bin/autom4te -B '../..'/lib -B '../..'/lib                      \
    --language=m4sugar          \
    --freeze            \
    --output=m4sugar.m4f
autom4te_perllibdir='../..'/lib AUTOM4TE_CFG='../../lib/autom4te.cfg'         ../../bin/autom4te -B '../..'/lib -B '../..'/lib                      \
    --language=m4sh         \
    --freeze            \
    --output=m4sh.m4f
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib/m4sugar'
Making all in autoconf
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib/autoconf'
autom4te_perllibdir='../..'/lib AUTOM4TE_CFG='../../lib/autom4te.cfg'         ../../bin/autom4te -B '../..'/lib -B '../..'/lib                      \
    --language=autoconf         \
    --freeze            \
    --output=autoconf.m4f
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib/autoconf'
Making all in autotest
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib/autotest'
autom4te_perllibdir='../..'/lib AUTOM4TE_CFG='../../lib/autom4te.cfg'         ../../bin/autom4te -B '../..'/lib -B '../..'/lib                      \
    --language=autotest         \
    --freeze            \
    --output=autotest.m4f
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib/autotest'
Making all in autoscan
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib/autoscan'
echo '# Automatically Generated: do not edit this file' >autoscan.list
sed '/^[#]/!q' ./autoscan.pre                  >>autoscan.list
( \
  sed -n '/^[^#]/p' ./autoscan.pre; \
  autom4te_perllibdir='../..'/lib AUTOM4TE_CFG='../../lib/autom4te.cfg'         ../../bin/autom4te -B '../..'/lib -B '../..'/lib         --cache '' -M -l autoconf -t'AN_OUTPUT:$1: $2      $3' \
) | LC_ALL=C sort                                      >>autoscan.list
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib/autoscan'
Making all in emacs
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib/emacs'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib/emacs'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib'
rm -f autom4te.cfg autom4te.tmp
sed -e 's|@SHELL[@]|/bin/bash|g' -e 's|@PERL[@]|/usr/bin/perl|g' -e 's|@bindir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/bin|g' -e 's|@pkgdatadir[@]|/usr/local/autoconf/share/autoconf|g' -e 's|@prefix[@]|/usr/local/autoconf|g' -e 's|@autoconf-name[@]|'`echo autoconf | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autoheader-name[@]|'`echo autoheader | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@autom4te-name[@]|'`echo autom4te | sed 's,x,x,'`'|g' -e 's|@M4[@]|/usr/bin/m4|g' -e 's|@AWK[@]|mawk|g' -e 's|@VERSION[@]|2.68|g' -e 's|@PACKAGE_NAME[@]|GNU Autoconf|g' ./autom4te.in >autom4te.tmp
chmod a-w autom4te.tmp
mv autom4te.tmp autom4te.cfg
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/lib'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/doc'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'autoconf.texi', needed by 'autoconf.info'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/doc'
Makefile:349: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68'
Makefile:284: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: autoconf-2.68 was written circa-2010. Why not install the later, compatible version with: `sudo apt-get install autoconf`?

Comment: I have used autoconf for configuring and making xgrafix. This is a software from PTSG. It was last updated around 2006 if I remember right and an error was that its not compatible with the current version of autoconf, use autoconf-2.68 instead.

Answer (score 1):

The message

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nickallen/autoconf-2.68/doc'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'autoconf.texi', needed by    'autoconf.info'.  Stop.
```

is saying tha the file doc/autoconf.texi doesn't exist. I checked ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.68.tar.gz and it is in that tarball. So if you don't have it in your doc directory, go download it again.

Another possibility is to use `make -k` (`--keep-going`) to ignore that error if you don't care about building the autoconf documentation.

Lastly, if none of this does it, there's [remake](http://bashdb.sf.net/remake) which allows can help you figure out what's wrong when there's an error or debug the Makefile.

Comment: @cgnick:  As you're a reputation 11 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**